# Doubly linked list: insert_before function C++

Tags: c++, insert, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am making a doubly linked list. Most of this code was provided with instructions to complete the insert_before and insert_after functions.

```
struct Node {
 int data; // each node holds an integer data
 Node* previous; // pointer to the previous node
 Node* next; // pointer to the next node
 Node(int d=0, Node* prv=NULL, Node* nxt=NULL) : data(d), previous(prv), next(nxt) {}
 Node* get_previous() const { return previous; }
 Node* get_next() const { return next; }
 Node* insert_before(int d); // insert the int before this node
                            // return a pointer to the inserted node
 Node* insert_after(int d); // insert the int after this node
                           // return a pointer to the inserted node
 void delete_before(); // delete the node before this node
 void delete_after(); // delete the node after this node
};

Node* Node::insert_before(int d) { 
  Node *newNode = new Node(d);
  newNode->previous = this->previous;
  newNode->next = this;
  this->previous = newNode;
  return newNode;
}
Node* Node::insert_after(int d) {
 Node *newNode = new Node(d);
 newNode->previous = this;
 newNode->next = this->next;
 this->next = newNode;
 return newNode;  
}
void display_list(Node* header, Node* trailer) {
  Node* p=header->get_next();
  while (p!=trailer) {
    cout << p->data << ", ";
    p=p->get_next();
  }
  cout << endl;
}
int main() {
 cout << "Create a new list" << endl;
 Node *header = new Node(-1);
 Node *trailer = new Node(-2);
 trailer->previous = header;
 header->next = trailer;
 cout << "list: ";
 display_list(header,trailer);
 cout << endl;

 // Insert 10 nodes at back with value 10,20,30,..,100
 cout << "Insert 10 nodes at back with value 10,20,30,..,100" << endl;
  for (int i=10;i<=100;i+=10) {
    trailer->insert_before(i);
  }
 cout << "list: ";
 display_list(header,trailer);
 cout << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

The insert_after function works perfectly, but for some reason the insert_before function is not working at all.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: I failed to see any problem in insert_before. Can you describe what is happening exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may be forgetting to change your `this->previous->next` in `insert_before` and `this->next->previous` in `insert_after`.

This is causing your list to skip over added nodes when traversing forwards and backward.

For example:

```
Node node1 = Node(1);
Node node2 = Node(2);
node1.next = &node2;
node2.previous = &head;

// NULL <- node1 <-> node2 -> NULL

node1.insert_after(3); 
// NULL <- node1 <-> node3 -> node2 -> NULL
//               <----------
// node2 is pointing back to node1 instead of 3

node2.insert_before(4);
// NULL <- node1 <-> node3   node4 <-> node2 -> NULL
//               <----------
//                         ---------->
// node 4 point back to node 1, while node3 points forward to node2
```

Answer (score 0):

Are your sure it doesn't work? I tried your node class and it works just fine. `Insert_after` adds every new element reference to the next element and `Insert_before` do the opposite thing, adds every new element reference to the previous one.